GeoServer does not respond if value in viewparams is negative
GeoServer's viewparams do not respond if value is negative. For example:
& viewparams=variable1:10;variable2:-10000
GeoServer return empty but if
& viewparams=variable1:10;variable2:0
GeoServer return many registros. For these two cases have registros in PostgreSQL database.

you ned to look in the log file to see what is going wrong
